# Strace command to display only system calls

Tags: android, emulation, system-calls, strace

I am trying to extract the sequence of system calls for an android application. Am using `Monkeyrunner` for random clicks. Could anyone kindly let me know how to get all the names only of the system call being used

This traces all the system calls:

```
strace -p 3934 -e trace=open -o /data/App1Advise.csv
```

Comment: try removing `-e trace=open`

Comment: @Rohit5k2 But now I am getting some unwanted things in my log App1Advise.csv. Is there a way that I could get only the names of the system calls ? I just want to evaluate the sequence of system calls.

Comment: For eg: clock_gettime,openat,read,writev,close  ... Something like this.

Comment: `strace -p 3934  trace=openat,close,clock_gettime,writev,read -o /data/App1Advise.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
strace -p 3934 -e trace=openat,close,clock_gettime,writev,read -o /data/App1Advise.csv
```

try `man strace` and you will see all the options.

Comment: Cool thanks! Just confirming does this command give me the list of all system call sequence or does it skip any ?

Comment: Whichever sys call you want you will have to add to the list. I shall have to check if there any command which shows all by default.

Comment: i tried with the argument -e trace=all but it gave me all other details of the system call too!

Comment: I shall check tomorrow for this specific case and let you know if I find any.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks